# nodejs issue: trying to install with npm with windows and getting eacces error

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I'm getting an error when trying to install a package with npm and I'm getting EACCES permission denied C:\Program Files\nodejs

I'm running 'npm install mongoose' for example and getting this error when running in that directory.

I'm new to this so any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `cmd.exe` as administrator. (rightclick, run as admin)

You also don't need to travers to node's directory, just do `npm install -g [package]`(-g if for a global install.)

Answer (score 2):

You should change the permissions on the folder nodejs is installed and give full access to your normal user account. You should avoid running npm as an administrator.

Comment: If this was my question I would accept this answer, thanks 